# Bash 1 liner: How to make a directory for each hour, 00 to 23?

Tags: bash, scripting

A process will be writing to a set of directories, one for each hour using date +%H notation, so 00, 01, 02... 22, 23.  I'm wanting to keep the leading 0 on single digit hours to keep sorted listings tidy.

I=00; until [ $I -gt 23 ]; do mkdir $I; let I=I+1; done

Has predictable effects of not keeping a leading 0 before the single digits.  I could just go and make them by hand, but feel there should be a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mkdir $(seq -w 00 23)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
mkdir {0{0..9},{10..23}}
```

Or in Bash 4:

```
 mkdir {00..23}
```

Comment: +1 for not spawning a subprocess.

Comment: +1 , from my IRC hang out: "seq(1) is a highly nonstandard external command used to count to 10 in silly Linux howtos. Use one of these instead: for x in {1..10} (bash3.x) or for ((x=1; x<=10; x++)) (bash 2.04+) or i=1; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do ...; i=$(($i+1)); done (ksh/POSIX)"

Comment: At least in Bash, you can do `((i++))` to increment a counter in a `while` loop (or elsewhere). Also, if you use double parentheses you can use `<=` and leave off the `$`: `i=1; while ((i<=10)); do echo $i; ((i++)); done`.

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in `seq -w 00 23`;do mkdir $i;done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a completely portable answer (to any Bourne-derived shell on pretty much any system that can run one of those), whereas all the other answers are at least a little non-portable, either rely on non-portable shell constructs or `seq`, which is common but neither in `POSIX` nor universal:

```
# start with a blank/clean "dirs" variable
dirs=
# iterate over the first digit
for i in 0 1 2
do
    # ..and the second digit for each first digit
    for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    do
        # add each digit combination to the dirs list
        dirs=$dirs\ $i$j
        # ..until we reach 23 - then we're done.
        case $i$j in 23) break 2; esac
    done
done
# finally make the directories
mkdir $dirs
```

Some notes:

Creating dirs initially ensures we don't accidentally use the value of an environment variable named `dirs`, in case we inherit one.

We could actually skip building the `$dirs` variable, and just call `mkdir $i$j`. But this way performs better (one mkdir process launched instead of 24) and is just as portable (if by some chance there's really a system out there were `mkdir` can only take one directory argument*, this is easy to adapt to call `mkdir` for each `$i$j` combination instead of building a `$dirs` variable).

The lack of quoting everywhere is both intentional and correct. Substitutions do not need to be quoted inside variable assignments and in the first part of the `case` statement: they don't undergo field splitting in those spots. And in the `mkdir` line at the end, we're relying on the field splitting to separate the directory list into separate names/arguments for `mkdir`.

* "Officially" MS-DOS and Windows has a `mkdir` which only takes one directory name, but at least on Windows 7 it works with multiple directory names, plus any port of a Bourne-like shell to those systems that I know of comes with it's own `mkdir`, and only weirdos like me would even think about that level of portability.

Comment: (I am aware the question is tagged with `bash`, but I believe this answer is sufficiently likely to be useful to system admins, etc, who may stumble upon this answer.)